# How to put a <div> within text inside a <p> in html+css?

Tags: html, css

So, I have a text, written in a `<p>`, and I want to add a `<div>` (that contains a word) in the middle of the text, exactly like the codeblocks are this question.

There is a small constrain in my case, the: `<p>` is `aligned-center`, and thus has `float: none`.

I'm sure I missing something, but I'm not being able to get it, and I also don't find any suitable combination of keywords that provides me the answer in google or stack.

I tried putting the div inside a `<code>`, but it didn't worked (even thought a simple word works).

Comment: Try using a span instead of a div

Comment: Please post a complete code example. And divs in p tags aren't valid HTML.

Comment: @Jeffman, Thanks! So, span stays inside <p> and <div> doesn't?

Comment: div is a block element, p is an inline element and you should never put block elements inside inline elements. It will just give you headaches debugging your design cross-browser.

Comment: @FilipHaglund - `<p>` are block not inline.

Comment: if possible use <span> tag instead of <div>, agree with Filip, "<Div>" being a block element, should not be used inside <p>

Comment: The problem in this case is putting a block-level div inside a p that contains line-level elements, like text, links, etc.

Comment: @J. C. Leitão, Yes,<Span> tag can be added withing <p>, as its not a block element. and this is the valid HTML approach. Refer :**http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp**

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply `display: inline` or `inline-block` to the div CSS ... and plz make a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) if you can ... it's very helpful.